# Network-Instance error on EF Core example from ReadTheDocs

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I can't get the example from this link to work:

[ASP.NET Core Application to New Database](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html)

I've copy pasted everything I could on the page but every time I browse the page, it says:

"Cannot open database "EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb" requested by the login. The login failed."

I am using an Admin account. I tried creating an SQL Server login with username and Password, but still error.

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**

I've tried manually creating the database and I can connect on it using the same connection string, but I want the migrations to run and automatically create the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you are following is a bit out of date. This is a major problem with the path .NET Core and associated frameworks have taken to final delivery. The migrations creation examples in the documentation you are following no longer work. You should use the examples found at:

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/data/ef-mvc/migrations.html

In the main ASP .Net Core documentation site.